# What was a Thermometer used for in the 14th century?

Tags: science-based

What was a Thermometer most commonly used for in the 14th century?

Comment: Fair warning, your question might get downvoted or closed if you keep the wording. I would reword it. Just repeating your question won't help you or me.

Comment: Also, this thread has the information you might be looking for. :https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/115047/medieval-method-of-measuring-temperature

Comment: Downvoted because basic research (e.g. Google "invention of thermometer") would show that the thermometer wasn't invented until several centuries after the 14th, thus couldn't commonly be used for anything.

Answer (score 4):

Probably for nothing.

> Various authors have credited the invention of the thermometer to Hero of Alexandria. The thermometer was not a single invention, however, but a development. Hero of Alexandria (10–70 AD) knew of the principle that certain substances, notably air, expand and contract and described a demonstration in which a closed tube partially filled with air had its end in a container of water.[8] The expansion and contraction of the air caused the position of the water/air interface to move along the tube.
>
> Such a mechanism was later used to show the hotness and coldness of the air with a tube in which the water level is controlled by the expansion and contraction of the gas. These devices were developed by several European scientists in the 16th and 17th centuries, notably Galileo Galilei[9] and Santorio Santorio.[3] As a result, devices were shown to produce this effect reliably, and the term thermoscope was adopted because it reflected the changes in sensible heat (the modern concept of temperature was yet to arise).[9] The difference between a thermoscope and a thermometer is that the latter has a scale.[10] Though Galileo is often said to be the inventor of the thermometer, there is no surviving document that he actually produced any such instrument.
>
> The first clear diagram of a thermoscope was published in 1617 by Giuseppe Biancani (1566 – 1624): the first showing a scale and thus constituting a thermometer was Santorio Santorio in 1625.[3] This was a vertical tube, closed by a bulb of air at the top, with the lower end opening into a vessel of water. The water level in the tube is controlled by the expansion and contraction of the air, so it is what we would now call an air thermometer.[11]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermometer#Early_developments

So thermometers were basically not invented unil the 17th century (1601-1700) and so could not have been used for anything during the 14th century (1301-1400).

Comment: So while a device that we may call a thermometer might have been built before 1600, it was actually only a thermoscope (i.e. it did not have a scale like thermometer does).

Comment: @Alexander:  But we have no evidence (AFAIK) that either thermometers or thermoscopes were ever made in the 14th century.  Since they didn't exist, they couldn't be used :-)

Comment: @jamesqf we know that the effect of thermal expansion/compression of gases or liquids was known by that time, so any device that demonstrates that can be called thermometer (or thermoscope).

Comment: This is a tongue-in-cheek [frame challenge](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7097/40609). I like it! +1.